# what is the use of .str[0] in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am having a dataframe df which has sales_area column i have to remove the MV- from the beginning of the columns_value

```
             Sales_area
          MV-Schmidt Carsten
          MV-Schmidt Carsten
          MV-Schmidt Carsten
          MV-Schmidt Carsten
          MV-Schmidt Carsten
```

so i used split function

```
d['SALES_AREA'].str.split('-')[1]
```

getting result

```
['MV', 'Schmidt Carsten']
```

when i try this

```
d['SALES_AREA'].str.split('-').str[1]
```

i got correct result

```
         Schmidt Carsten
         Schmidt Carsten
         Schmidt Carsten
         Schmidt Carsten
```

i got results. but i am not able to understand why i am getting result when i use str[0] instead of [0]

Comment: `d['SALES_AREA'].str.split('-')[1]` gives you the item at index `1` of the Series returned by `split`. `str[1]` is the "vectorial" way to slice all rows at once, getting the second item (if existing). You could also use `d['SALES_AREA'].str.extract(r'^[^-]+-(.*)', expand=False)`

Answer (score 1):

When you use `d['SALES_AREA'].str.split('-')[1]` you are effectively doing this:

```
d = pd.DataFrame(['MV-Schmidt Carsten', 'MV-Schmidt Carsten', 'MV-Schmidt Carsten'], columns=['Sales_area'])
d['Split'] = d['Sales_area'].str.split('-')
print(d)

           Sales_area                  Split
0  MV-Schmidt Carsten  [MV, Schmidt Carsten]
1  MV-Schmidt Carsten  [MV, Schmidt Carsten]
2  MV-Schmidt Carsten  [MV, Schmidt Carsten]
```

Your first line of code is the equivalent of `d['Split'][1]`; It returns the second element of the dataframe after applying the split function, i.e. the list of the two split values.

```
['MV', 'Schmidt Carsten']
```

By doing `d['SALES_AREA'].str.split('-').str[1]` you are instead returning the second element of the list created by the split() function. You can also index this like `d['Sales_area'].str.split('-')[1][1]` to return the second value of a specific row

Answer (score 1):

The `str` attribute produces a proxy of type `StringMethods` that wraps `d['Sales_AREA']`. The `split` method then is not invoked on the column itself, but on each `str` value in that column. The results are then returned in a new `Series` object with the same shape.

`df[...].str[0]` works because `...[0]` invokes the `__getitem__` method of the object, so `df[...].str[0]` is the same as `df[...].str.__getitem__(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

In pandas, when you use the "str.split()" function on a column, it splits the values into a list of substrings based on the delimiter specified making a new column where each value is a list.

To remove the 'MV-' from the beginning of the values in the SALES_AREA column

```
d['SALES_AREA'] = d['SALES_AREA'].str.replace('MV-', '')
```

This replaces 'MV-' with an empty string.

Or you can use

```
.strip('MV-')
```

This will remove MV- from the start and end of string.

Answer (score 0):

Note the difference:

- `[1]` selects the second element of a series, equivalent to `.iloc[1]`. Since the series is a series of lists of substrings created with `.str.split()`, it results in a single **list** of substrings.
- `.str[1]` selects the second string of a list of substrings, row-wise. It results in a **series** of substrings.

---

```
import pandas as pd

strings = ['lorem^ipsum^dolor',
           'sit^amet^consectetur',
           'adipiscing^elit^sed',
           'do^eiusmod^tempor']

df = pd.DataFrame({'strings': strings})
print('Dataframe:')
print(df)

# First syntax
a_row_of_split  = df['strings'].str.split('^')[1]
print('\n' 'With [1]:')
print(a_row_of_split)

# What you did:
# 1. Each string in df has been split, resulting in a series
# 2. The second element (row) of the series has been selected
# This was equivalent to
# a_row_of_split  = df['strings'].str.split('^').iloc[1]

# Second syntax
a_series  = df['strings'].str.split('^').str[1]
print('\n' 'With .str[1]')
print(a_series)

# What you did:
# 1. Each string in df has been split, resulting in a series
# 2. With str accessor, each second string was extracted row-wise
```

---

```
Dataframe:
                strings
0     lorem^ipsum^dolor
1  sit^amet^consectetur
2   adipiscing^elit^sed
3     do^eiusmod^tempor

With [1]:
['sit', 'amet', 'consectetur']

With .str[1]
0      ipsum
1       amet
2       elit
3    eiusmod
Name: strings, dtype: object
```